# Random point on a square floor

Tags: unity, c#, random

I have a flat 10x10 surface (floor) made out of cubes of 1x1x1.

I am spawning objects from the "sky" and I want them to fall on random points of the surface without exceeding the surface limits.

Is there anything similar to `Random.onUnitSphere` to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`Random.Range(min, max)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) allows you to generate pseudo-random numbers in a specific range. Use it twice, and you can get a random point in a rectangle:

```
Vector3 randomPoint = new Vector3( Random.Range(0f, 10f), 
                                   0, 
                                   Random.Range(0f, 10f) );
```

This of course assumes that your rectangle is between the coordinates 0:0:0 and 10:0:10 and that it's axis-aligned. If that's not the case, then you might have to transform the above vector to be relative to the position, rotation and scale of the rectangle. If your rectangle is a game-object, then you can actually do that by using its `transform` (which I here assume to be in a variable named `rectangleTransform`) using the method [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html):

```
randomPoint = rectangleTransform.TransformPoint( randomPoint );
```

Comment: it says that GameObject does not contain a definition for TransformPoint

Comment: @ThorvaldÓlavsenV. TransformPoint is a method of the transform of the game object, not of the game object itself. Try `rectangle.transform.TransformPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a point in an axis-aligned rectangle uniformly at random by choosing:

```
point.x = center.x + Random.Range(-0.5, 0.5) * width;
point.y = center.y;
point.z = center.z + Random.Range(-0.5, 0.5) * depth;
```

In your case, width and depth are both 10.